# Purpose of @class in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, ios4

I have the following code

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "SecondLevelViewController.h"
@class DisclosureButtonController;

@interface DisclosureButtonController : SecondLevelViewController {
    NSArray *list;
    DisclosureButtonController *childController;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *list;

@end
```

I can`t get what

```
@class DisclosureButtonController;
```

means.

Can anyone explain to me ?

Answer (score 3):

It simply tells the compiler that `DisclosureButtonController` is a `Class` that is defined elsewhere.

If you remove it you should get an error at `DisclosureButtonController *childController;` because the compiler doesn't know what you want him to do at this line.

From Apple Doc [Defining a class](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocDefiningClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH12-TPXREF124)

> The @class directive minimizes the amount of code seen by the compiler and linker, and is therefore the simplest way to give a forward declaration of a class name. Being simple, it avoids potential problems that may come with importing files that import still other files. For example, if one class declares a statically typed instance variable of another class, and their two interface files import each other, neither class may compile correctly.

---

EDIT: I just saw that the `@class` directive is superfluous there, because you are declaring this class at the next line. Maybe there was a `@protocol` that used the class in between `@class` and `@interface`. But in your special case you could remove it without problems. It's redundant.